# How do I get the calculation of the sum of the items in an array with a for loop?

Tags: javascript

So I am  a bit lost on this one, so what I did was create the for loop that shows their index, for example: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.

```
let tasks =["swim", "study", "eat", "break", "sleep", "Cook", "Clean", "watch TV", "Train", "Code"]
let x;


for(x of tasks)
{
    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML += x + " ";
    console.log(x);
}
```

so the above code I used the for of loop which gets index of each item.
What I am trying to do is how do I get the add each index to each other, so it should be 1 + 2 + 3...etc.

```
//Activity 2 - Edit the loop created above, to now calculate the sum of all the items leading up to 10. e.g. 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
//console.log your output
//Add your code below

let index;
let sum;


for(x = 0; x < tasks.length; x++)
{
    index = document.getElementById("sumOftasks").innerHTML += x + " ";
}
```

Comment: Use a [`for` statement instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) and sum up the indexes.

Comment: Your first loop doesn't get the index of each item, it gets each item.

Comment: use a for statement where? where I used the ```for(x of tasks)
{
    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML += x + " ";
    console.log(x);
}```

Comment: Use `sum += x` to add the indexes.

Comment: @Andy Instead of what? He already has a `for` statement.

Comment: You can also use the formula: `sum = tasks.length * (tasks.length-1) / 2;`

Comment: thanks @Barmar, that seemed to have worked it looks like its 55, but its going 55 like 10 times, its like its looping 55 10 time over. example 55 55 55...

Comment: You shouldn't print the total every time, just at the end.

Comment: I see what I did wrong, I had ```index = document.getElementById("sumOftasks").innerHTML += sum + " ";``` isntead of ```index = document.getElementById("sumOftasks").innerHTML = sum + " ";```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return values of array and when you sum it it Will give you result NaN

You can get value from array, Find index and Sum it.

```
    for(x of tasks)
    {
                
     let index = tasks.indexOf(x);
 document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML += index + " ";
    }
```

It will help.